# Changing the Container DataItem in codebehind for GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am wondering if i can change the Container.DataItem in codebehind in a gridview. I mean, if i want to change the Dataitem from "SellingPaymentMethod" to "DeliveryPaymentmethod" depending on a condition.

I am using the same stored procedure for getting the information both for selling and delivery. So if it is a selling it should be SellingPaymentmethod, else it should be DeliveryPaymentmethod. This is in ASP.Net using C#.

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="70" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblSellingPaymentMethod" runat="server"
         Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"SellingPaymentMethod") %>'>
      </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>



if(Condition1 = "Selling")
{
    use sellingpaymentmethod container
}
else
{
    use deliverypaymentmethod
}
```

EDIT:

```
if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (DataRow dtrCurrentRow in (((System.Data.DataView)grdDetail.DataSource)).Table.Rows) 
    {
        //DataRow row = (DataRow)e.Row.DataItem;
        Label lblPaymentMethod = e.Row.FindControl("lblPaymentMethod") as Label;
        Label lblBalance = e.Row.FindControl("lblTotalSold") as Label;
        Label lblBalanceCollected = e.Row.FindControl("lblTotalCollected") as Label;

        if (lblTypeofDay.Text == "Selling")
        {
            lblPaymentMethod.Text = dtrCurrentRow["SellingPaymentMethod"].ToString();
        }
        else if (lblTypeofDay.Text == "Delivery")
        {
            lblPaymentMethod.Text = dtrCurrentRow["DeliveryPaymentmethod"].ToString();
        }
     }
```

This is how i used your code. And i am not sure why all the rows are having the last row values in the paymentmethod column.

And i have the databinding code in the btnSubmit_OnClick function

```
DataView myDataView = new DataView();
myDataView = dsnew.Tables[0].DefaultView;
grdDetail.DataSource = myDataView;
grdDetail.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `RowDataBound` event handler and change it there.

Aspx:

```
<asp:GridView id="gridView1" runat="server" 
    OnRowDataBound="gridView1_RowDataBound" />
```

Code Behind:

```
public void gridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        return;
    }

    DataRow row = (DataRow)e.Row.DataItem;

    Label lblSellingPaymentMethod = 
        e.Row.FindControl("lblSellingPaymentMethod") as Label;

    if(condition == true)
    {
        lblSellingPaymentMethod.Text = row["sellingpaymentmethod"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        lblSellingPaymentMethod.Text = row["deliverypaymentmethod"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: For all the rows, paymentmethod is showing as the last one in the table. I mean the value is not sticking to each row, instead all the rows have the last row values. Why is it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean... Each row in your `GridView` is bound to the last row of your `DataSet`? That shouldn't be happening, `e.Row.DataItem` is the `DataRow` of the current row out of the `DataSet`. Please post your code and an explanation of what's going on.